# Sublime Text: Is it possible to build a simple - headless - objective-c app?

Tags: objective-c, sublimetext2

So, think the classic beginner C programming right of passage: hello world. But written in Objective-C.

For reasons I prefer not to get into, I don't want to use XCode but rather my new love, Sublime Text.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a bit of digging and found this which lets me build and run entirely within Sublime Text which is what I need. Still testing: https://gist.github.com/chendo/4398077

Answer (score 0):

Paste the following into Sublime and save the file as main.m

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
       NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

       NSLog(@"Hello, World!");

       [pool drain];
       return 0; 
    }
```

Then in the terminal navigate to the file with cd and type:

```
gcc -framework Foundation main.m -o NAME_OF_YOUR_APP
```

And run the app by typing:

```
./NAME_OF_YOUR_APP
```